# Create a custom password complexity rule in group policy

Tags: windows, passwords, windows-server-2012, group-policy

Is it possible to create a custom password complexity policy in group policy? I'm not asking if you can enable password complexity, more that i'm asking how to change the default complexity?

Answer (score 1):

The built-in complexity requirements can be activated this way :

- Run Local Security Policy
- Select Account Policy > Password Policy
- Enable at least "Passwords must meet complexity requirements setting"

The explanation of this policy is :

> If this policy is enabled, passwords must meet the following minimum
>   requirements:
>
> - Not contain the user's account name or parts of the user's full name that exceed two consecutive characters
> - Be at least six characters in length
>
>   - Contain characters from three of the following four categories:
>   - English uppercase characters (A through Z)
>   - English lowercase characters (a through z)
>   - Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
>   - Non-alphabetic characters (for example, !, $, #, %)
>
> Complexity requirements are enforced when passwords are changed or
>   created.

If you need more control than that, see the following references :

- [Tutorial: How to setup Default and Fine Grain Password Policy](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2011/08/tutorial-how-to-setup-default-and-fine-grain-password-policy/)
- [Password Filters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecMgmt/password-filters)
  and also in the SDK
  [Sample Password Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722439.aspx).